# /var/lib/docker/containers folder is empty

Tags: docker

I have docker engine installed on an Ubuntu Focal 20.04 machine.
When I run containers, if am not wrong, there should be folders corresponding to each of the containers created in the /var/lib/docker/containers folder and they should include a .json file with the name of the container which should include all the logs from the container.
The problem which I am facing is that, there are no folders within /var/lib/docker/containers.
Just wanted to check if I am missing any configurations/steps.

Comment: How did you install docker? Is docker running directly on the host, in a snap, rootless, or some other configuration? Accessing this folder directly is non-standard and error prone. It would be advisable to use the docker API's since the backend storage could change without warning from docker.

Comment: Had used the steps at the following link for the installation : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/.                                                                                             sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io. Have docker running on the same host as a service.

Comment: Was wondering if I had missed any steps or if I had "mis" installed it. And yes, I am able to see the logs using docker logs <container id>. Will you be able to direct on where those logs are stored? .i,e, from where the logs are pulled when we run docker logs <container id>

Answer (score 0):

to check the containers you have you should do `docker ps -a` in a shell
explooring the folders is not a customer feature and can change between versions without warning...